I want to get Newly listed Solana token for trading Via API
I am trying to make webpage where i can get Newly listed Solana token for trading Via API. Is there any free service for API available?

an easy way to track new tokens would be to set up a webhook to monitor the token metadata program. Here is a blog post that breaks down how to do this: https://www.helius.dev/blog/how-to-fetch-newly-minted-tokens-with-helius
Please note I am an employee at Helius Labs.

Thanks. Bro i stuck in a big situation can you help me? https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/13283/fetch-top-solana-token-account-holders-via-api
